# Mac font on website on PC

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I like how fonts look on a Mac. Is it possible to render something similar in a website and have it work on all operating systems and browsers? I'm aware of font-face but I can't seem to find a clean font. Ideally I want Arial but more smooth.

Comment: do you like mac fonts or how mac RENDERS the fonts?

Comment: Verdana is not well liked, some links: [Verdana must die for the good of the planet](http://davidsimpson.me/2009/03/23/verdana-must-die-for-the-good-of-the-planet/), [Don't smoke Verdana!](http://virtuelvis.com/archives/2004/01/avoid-verdana).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Mac-font-specific, but: in order to have a font that is available on every platform, you could use webfonts. [Google Webfonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) provides them, for example. The only thing you have to do is include a Stylesheet in your `head`-area and you are ready to go. Every modern browser is able to load and show those webfonts.

Just take a look at a gallery, there are a lot fonts that have a nice and smooth look.

Comment: However every browser renders fonts differently.

Comment: I agree that you should try Google Fonts. Perhaps try Open Sans and see if that renders the way you want on different platforms: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open+Sans

Answer (score 1):

Take the font from your filesystem and upload it to this website.  Use the cufon script to render your images.  I did this on my profile website, and a few others.  It looks pretty nice, though can have a slight delay.

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/